# JPA repository method returns doubled results

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

A Teacher entity has List of vacations. I am using JPA repository (TeacherRepository extends JpaRepository<Teacher, Integer>).

When I retrieve vacations for teacher with id=1, I get his two vacations twice:

```java
System.out.println(teacherRepository.findById(1).get().getVacations());
```

Output:

```
[start: 2000-01-01, end: 2000-02-01, start: 2000-05-01, end: 2000-06-01, start: 2000-01-01, end: 2000-02-01, start: 2000-05-01, end: 2000-06-01] // wrong output: each vacation twice
```

But if I first trigger findAll() method, everything is fine:

```java
teacherRepository.findAll();
System.out.println(teacherRepository.findById(1).get().getVacations());
```

Output:

```
[start: 2000-01-01, end: 2000-02-01, start: 2000-05-01, end: 2000-06-01]
```

Why?

UPD. Teacher entity implementation:

```java
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    // name, mail, phone skipped
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Vacation> vacations;
}
```

Comment: maybe also show how you are binding Teacher to Vacation in your DTO.

Comment: Edited my question, added info.

Comment: The simplest way would be to bind to `Set<Vacation>`  instead of `List<Vacation>`, no duplicates in sets.

OFC that won't resolve the underlying issue. Also won't work it unique instances are created by JPA.